# Is there such a thing as an international mobile wireless provider?

Tags: usa, international-travel, internet, latvia

After searching for a short time, the only promising lead I've found is [global gig](http://globalgig.com/learn-more.aspx), which claims to

> stay connected in the USA, UK, Australia, Ireland, Hong Kong, Sweden and Denmark.

Which doesn't include Latvia, where I'll be staying.

Is there any way to get mobile wireless access that can be used in both the United States and Latvia?

For the record, I currently use Verizon wireless in the States, and though there appears to be a [global data program](http://www.verizonwireless.com/wcms/global/globaltravelprogram.html), there's no mention of a mobile wireless (MiFi) unit, just data for smartphone use. Tethering would run me $2.50/MB, and seeing as how I'll need to use this for Google hangouts, is out of the question due to price.

Is there a practical way to ensure I can connect abroad without relying on where I'll be without paying a high price for it? I expect there to be some wired/wireless connection available to me, but I would still like to look into other options anyway.

Comment: There is no such a cheap data connections for roaming. The best would be buying local data sim cards or any other connection method with a cheap data plan which is almost available everywhere. One Sim card or the equivalent for everywhere, never!

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/16854/444

Comment: They advertise heavily in Asia. There is no list of countries provided, but you could email the guy listed http://matrix-sim.webs.com/

Comment: What's your price range?

Comment: Maybe you should state if you want to buy it in the USA or not. A lot of phone contracts are only available in one country - and you need to have a mailing address there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Boingo for accessing private wifi at airports and cafes that you would otherwise have to pay for. It is about $10 per month and works in many countries including Latvia. I did a search for hotspots at http://wifi.boingo.com and they seems to mostly be in Riga. So if you are staying there great, but if you are going out in the countryside not great.

If you want cell phone data then I have just bought local USB modem device for about $50 and SIM card with local data plan. I have done this in Boliva, Paraguay and Chile, haven't tried in Latvia but I assume they have them there too.

Finally when I travel in less developed countries there are always lots of internet cafes and they will often let you connect your laptop direct to their internet via a cable if you pay them a small fee. This gives great speed and cost of about $1 per hour. I am not sure where Latvia is on the internet development scale so you will have to scope this idea out on the ground.

Comment: I think the correct answer is to rent as much free internet as possible. In the countryside, you have to unplug, it's a good idea to do so anyway `:)`. Everyone else has internet for you to use.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's just a case of knowing what search terms to use. :) There are several that cover many countries - some Europe, some claim up to 230 countries (although I contest that there are even that many countries in existence), and others are just discounted. I'll list a few I found:

- [Global Sim](http://www.globalsim.covermore.com.au/)
- [Woolworths Global Roaming](http://www.woolworthsglobalroaming.com.au/)
- [Jetstar Global Sim](http://www.jetstar.com/au/en/what-we-offer/jetstar-global-sim)
- [Travel Sim](http://www.travelsim.net.au/)
- [Roaming Sim](http://www.roamingsim.com.au/?gclid=CJncovfDy7cCFWhfpgodNl8A8Q)
- [Go Sim](http://www.gosim.com/?gosimaus)
- [World Sim](http://www.worldsim.com/)

Worth noting that I'm in Australia at present, so my searches are returning a lot of Aussie-centric sites.  I used google in Canada and Europe to find this in the past, by searching for terms like `global sim` and `travel sim`.

Comment: These are mostly for calls, and internet is so expensive...

Answer (score -1):

Try www.travelersmobile.com they have what you are looking for.  An international MiFi device and plans.